# Replacing phrase with "en"

Tags: pronoms

The pronoun "en" is frequently used to replace a noun. But can it be used to replace a phrase? As in

> Est-il capable de faire ses devoirs?
>
> Oui, il en est capable.

or

> A-t-elle essayé de faire ses devoirs?
>
> Oui, elle en a essayé.

Comment: Interesting question. The answer should consist in explaining why in the particular contexts you give the first sentence is correct but not the second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first phrase is grammatically correct, the second one is not. In the second case you would have to use *le* (which would elide to *l’*). The reason for this is that the *de* following the verb *essayer* is part of the object of that verb and not the verb itself. In the first phrase, *de* is an inherent part of the construction *être capable de*.

This becomes more clear if you replace the object clause (what you are trying to replace with *en*) with *cela*:

> - Est-il capable **de *cela*** ?
> - Oui, il **en**  est capable.

In this case *de* is part of the verb construction. In the following phrase it is not:

> - A-t-elle essayé ***cela*** ?
> - Oui, elle **l’a** essayé.

As you can clearly see in the phrases above, the correct construction is *être capable **de** quelque chose* and *essayer quelque chose*. As a result, when replacing the phrase with a pronoun in the answer to the question, you cannot use *en* in with *essayer*.

More specifically, in the first case, *en* replaces *faire ses devoirs* since *de* is part of the verb construction. In the second case, ***le*** is used to replace *de faire ses devoirs*, since *de* **is not** part of the verb construction.

Some French verbs are followed by *de* only when their object is a (subordinate) clause and not when the object is a noun. However, there are some that do not take *de* in that case either:

> Il espère/souhaite/veux/doit *faire ses devoirs*.

Yet, as stated earlier, some verbs do:

> Il essaye/envisage/tente/oublie ***de*** faire ses devoirs.

There is no grammatical rule to figure out when a verb does or does not take *de* with a clause as a subject. The rule of thumb is to just know your verbs and replace the object clause by *cela* or *quoi* to figure out whether or not *de* belongs to the verb or to the clause. If it is an inherent part of the verb, you replace the object by *en*. If not, you use *le* instead.