# Pronoun for "obligé de faire quelque chose"

Tags: pronoms, verbes

> Est-on obligé de faire cet exercice ?

What can the response be, from among the following?

> (a) Oui, on en est obligé.
>
> (b) Oui, on y est obligé.
>
> (c) Oui, on l'est obligé.
>
> (d) Oui, on est obligé.

Since the phrase is *être obligé de faire quelque chose*, the temptation would be to use *en*. But I'm not sure whether *de* is part of the verb or not; if not we would [have to use *le*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22381/replacing-phrase-with-en). On the other hand there is also the phrase *obligé quelqu'un à quelque chose*, but I don't think it applies in this case.

Comment: Your answers are not right: Est-on obligé [adjective] de faire cet exercice? Oui, on est obligé de le  faire. The pronouns here come after the DE or à:  It replaces: faire l'exercise.

Comment: You need to provide the antecedents. The current question does not contain enough detail. In any case, I pretty much answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is:

> Which ones of these pronouns, ***y***, ***en***, ***le***, or "no pronoun" can replace ***de le faire*** in
>
> *– On **xx** est pas obligé.*

The verb dictates the pronoun to use. To find which one is expected, we shouldn't look at the question but instead know how would be written its full answer (without the pronoun).

---

With:

> *Est-on **obligé(s)** de faire cet exercice ?*

A full answer would be:

> *Oui, **on nous** oblige **à** le faire.*

As the grammar books tell, ***y*** replaces ***à*** so the right answer is

> *Oui, on **y** est obligé(s).*

Same would happen with other past participle like *contraint / astreint / autorisé à le faire*.

The alternate implicit reference with no pronoun is also possible, although informal:

> *Oui, on est obligé(s)*.

---

On the other hand, if we use a different set of past participles:

> *Est-on **dispensé(s)** de faire cet exercice ?*

A full answer would be:

> *Oui, **on nous** dispense **de** le faire.*

The grammar books tells ***en*** replaces ***de*** so the right answer is

> *Oui, on **en** est dispensé(s).* (or still the informal *oui, on est dispensé(s)*)

Same with *exonérés*, *privés*, *empêchés*, *capables* although with the latter, the full answer would be:

> *Oui, **on est** capables **de** le faire.* because *capables* is not a past participle.

---

In both case, ***le*** is also possible, but only if replacing the whole clause:

> *Oui, on **l**'est*.

---

Off topic: **On** can replace any personal pronoun, including "people in general, anyone" (pronom indéfini) and a defined group of people including me (pronom défini).

In the first case, i.e. "whoever susceptible to do it", the singular **must** be used. e.g. *En France, on est obligé d'avoir 18 ans pour voter*.

In the last case, i.e. "we, the students enrolled in that class", the plural **can** logically be used. e.g. *Nous, les élèves de 4<sup>e</sup> II, on est  **obligés*** de faire cet exercice*.

Oddly enough, the plural is still not mandatory here, unlike the feminine which is required when the group in exclusively female. e.g. *Alors les filles, on est **grande**(s) maintenant !*.

Comment: Could you please explain why the "s" is needed in "obligés" even though the pronoun "on" is singular? Also, why is "y" the correct pronoun despite "obligé **de**"?

Comment: @user11550: The *s* is not needed in this case. It's better to leave it out actually.

Comment: @jlliagre Est-on obligé de manger ce sucre? Oui, on est obligé d'en manger. Voilà ce qui manque et voilà ce qui peut prêter à confusion. Je ne comprends pas le refus des francophones ici de voir cette confusion éventuelle dans l'esprit d'un locuteur non-natif. Evidemment, le phrase a) ne marche pas. Je suis d'accord avec vous.

Comment: user11550, *On* can replace any personal pronoun, including "people in general, anyone" (*pronom indéfini*) and a defined group of people including me (*pronom défini*). I was assuming the last case, i.e. "we, the students enrolled in that class" in which case the plural can logically be used. Oddly enough, the plural is still not mandatory unlike the feminine which is required when the group in exclusively female: *On est belle(s)*.

Comment: @Lambie *Est-on obligé de manger ce sucre? Oui, on est obligé d'en manger.* is correct but *Oui, on y est obligé* too. I might be missing your point so can you elaborate about the confusion you believe francophones are refusing to see?

Comment: "Oui, on y est obligé" works perfectly, but IMHO, just "oui, on est obligé" would be more usual to me, honestly. "On est obligé" d'en manger" works too. You can think really hard and find nuances and differences between all three if you want, but to us native french speakers, I don't think we would pay too much attention to these differences in every day life. All three are broadly equivalent in conversation, IMHO.

Comment: "Est-on obligé de manger ce sucre? Oui, on est obligé d'en manger." could work, but I hear "ce sucre", the first image that comes to my mind is of a sugar cube, not bulk sugar. So I would say "Oui, on est obligé de le manger." That works. If you want to say "Oui, on est obligé d'en manger", you would be referring to bulk sugar, which you would have introduced with "Est-on obligé de manger du sucre?". Usually. You can weasel your way out of that though, and have "ce sucre" refer to bulk sugar, and say "d'en manger" if you want.

Comment: @Frank Yes, depending if *ce sucre* means "this kind of sugar" or "this sugar cube", we need to use *d'en manger* or *de le manger*.

Comment: "With: Est-on obligé(s) de faire cet exercice ? A full answer would be: Oui, on nous oblige à le faire." Isn't the "on" in the answer different from the "on" in the question? The "on" in the question refers to the people who have to do the exercise, while the "on" in the answer refers to the people who order the first group of people to do the exercise.

Comment: Yes, these *on* are different. The first one is "we" while second is "they", i.e. "the ones having authority". *On* is very flexible in French, as I already wrote in my off-topic addendum.

Answer (score 1):

La bizarrerie tient moins à l'infélicité de *en* qu'à l'apparition de *de* dans la forme passive à la place du *à* à l'actif.

> Est-on obligé **de** faire cet exercice ?
>   Qui vous oblige **à** faire cet exercice ?

La pronominalisation de l'actif en *y* est une des deux possibilités pour un complément en *à* :

> Jean parle **à** Marie => Jean **lui** parle
>   Jean pense **à** Marie => Jean **y** pense

Ce qui donne avec la phrase en question :

> Qui vous **y** oblige ?

En mettant le tout au passif :

> On **y** est obligé (par le prof).

Une question complémentaire serait donc l'origine du *de* dans la forme sans pronominalisation.

Answer (score 0):

The question

> Est-on obligé de faire cet exercice ?

Can be answered with:

> (a) Oui, on en est obligé. - NO
>
> (b) Oui, on y est obligé. - YES
>
> (c) Oui, on l'est obligé. - NO
>
> (d) Oui, on est obligé. - YES
>
> (e) Oui, on est obligé de le faire.

My favorites would be, in order of preference (d) and (e). (b) is still correct, but sounds "funny" to me.

Answer (score 0):

The verbe *obliger* involves the preposition *à* when you're forcing someone to do something. *De* rather comes when it's an impersonal obligation. Now notice:

---

Être persuadé de X. --> J'en suis persuadé.

Être heureux de X. --> En être heureux.

Être capable de X. --> Il en est capable.

In all of thoses cases you can form a sentence with *en* because of the preposition *de*. But have a look on the grammatical nature of X. It can be either a verb or a noun. Yet when you say "Obligé de X", X cannot be a noun, only a verb. And it's not possible to say "En être obligé". I don't know if that is the explanation to your point but there's likely a correlation. Actually, when constructing the sentence with "obliger",it's intuitive to use *à*: compare with English "to be assigned *to* something
", whose meaning is close. But anyway that's most likely an exception because 95% of the time you'll use *en* when you see *de*.

Answer (score -2):

It depends on what comes after the DE.

Examples: obliger de faire **ses devoirs**: obliger de **les** faire;

obliger de **faire la vaiselle**: obliger de **la** faire.

obliger d'aller à l'école: obliger **d'y** aller;

obliger de bouffer **du pain**; obliger **d'en** bouffer.

Tout dépend de ce qui vient après.  Si c'est un partitif (obliger de verbe + du pain, de la marmelade, du sucre, faire du bateau) manger du gateau, boire de la limonade, utiliser du sucre, le pronom EN est de rigueur.

Obliger d'en [verb] manger, boire, utiliser, etc.

I did not conjugate the verb obliger to keep it simple. On n'est pas obligé de le faire.

The possibilities are: les, la, le, y and en

Here's a more complicated one:

On est obligé de **lui donner beaucoup d'argent** toutes les semaines. That's with an indirect object + a "partitif".

On est obligé de **lui en donner beaucoup** toutes les semaines.

Or this one: obliger de le voir au travail et non pas chez lui;

Which becomes:
obliger de l'y voir. So, it can get hairy though this one is not very usual.

Bear in mind the idiom: obliger de s'y faire: to have to accept some situation or other.

Comment: It is not clear how you are answering to the question, i.e. telling which suggestions of the list are correct or not, and why.

Comment: @jlliagre You must be kidding. Est-on obligé à  faire cet exercice? Non, rien n'y oblige.

Comment: Do you mean the question need to use *obligé à faire* or is it just a typo?

Comment: Also, we say "tu m'obliges **a** le faire?", not "tu m'obliges de le faire".

Comment: ***On est obligé de le faire***. I did not say: "Tu m'obliges" de le faire, did I??? I said: être obliger de faire quelque chose without any indirect object. Of course, obliger quelqu'un à faire quelque chose. http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/obliger-a-de-a46980829

Comment: My sentence was: On n'est pas obligé de le faire. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: The original question is about the pronoun to use on the passive auxillary not on the controlled verb...

Comment: The original OP's question was not fully explained and based on a mistaken premise.