# vous en avez une... vs vous avez une

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-personnels

Would I be right in saying that the difference here when adding the *en* is just emphasis? I struggle to see the meaning of *en* used in this way. The translation to English of sentences with the *en* don't shed any light either.

Is it just emphasising or what?

EDIT:OK some examples where I heard this with *en* but don't see how it would be different if the *en* wasn't there:

```
1. Et si vous en avez le courage.
2. Vous en avez une tout au début.
```

Comment: Welcome to French Language.  Can you give more context? None of these two groups of words will stand on their own. *Vous **en** avez une*, has a personal pronoun *en*  that stands for something, only the context  will say what. *Vous avez une* is an unfinished sentence because we expect a grammatical object after *avez*. It would the same if you asked what is the difference in English between "you've got one" and "you've got", I'd ask you: what is it that you've got?

Comment: "you've got one" and "you've got"? But that would mean 'une' is not there...? I'm talking about the difference between the 'en' being there or not. It would be very easy to explain the difference between "you've got one" and "you've got". Anyway I've added the context where I came across this.

Comment: So you've dropped *une* in sentence 1, ...  but anyway that's enough to see where the problem lies.

Comment: No I haven't dropped anything, they are just two examples (independent of each other) where I came across 'vous en avez'....? I was providing a context for more clarity.

Comment: Title of your question: vous en avez **une**… vs vous avez **une**.

Comment: Yes that was just so it wasn't too short, otherwise like you say there's no context. The key part was 'en' so I was just writing "vous en avez une… vs vous avez une" as a direct comparison, one with 'en' and one without. I only came across one sentence with "vous en avez une" in it so I only used one in my two examples. But both examples use 'vous en avez' which is what I want understand, not so much the 'une' part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*En* in those sentences is a personal pronoun. It usually represents something that has previously been mentioned. The use of *en* is different in each sentence you give. We'll have to add context to explain.

> Et si vous **en** avez le courage vous rentrerez à pied.

*En* represents *rentrer à pied*. It could be dropped in that particular sentence without altering comprehension but most people would leave it.  *En* is used here because *avoir le courage* would be followed by *de* (*vous avez le courage **de** rentrer à pied*), there's a question about it here: [Replacing phrase with "en"](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/22381/358)

> – Est-ce qu'il y a des publicités dans ce magazine ?
>   –  Vous en avez une (deux, trois, etc...) tout au début.

*En* is necessary when expressing a notion of quantity and no actual noun phrase is specified. It could not be dropped. In the above example, *en* represents *publicité*. In the same way we could add to the previous sentence: "... *et vous en avez une autre à la fin*."

Both youre examples use *avoir*, but of course, the use of *en* is not linked to *avoir*.
(*Si vous vous **en** rappeler rapportez moi des pommes*.  *Il y a des oiseaux dans le jardin, j'**en** vois deux*.)

<sub>You say you have been trying to translate into English, but one can never translate word for word. In the examples you give English does not translate *en* at all.

 1. if you've got the guts...   / if you feel up to it

 2. There's one right at the beginning.

But you'd translate *en* in *Tu veux des biscuits ? oui, j'**en** veux bie*n. (yes, I'd like **some**)</sub>

Comment: Another possible English interpretation of the first sentence, in the sense of a tedious task *(si vous **en** avez le courage)*: if you're up **for this**.

Comment: @Feelew You're right that in the case of walking home it is more a question of feeling up to it than having the guts !

Comment: Ok that's great, thanks. I guess my two examples were good then since they were both completely different ways to use 'en'. I realise translating to English is not ideal, in fact I try to avoid it almost entirely but I must understand what I'm hearing/reading or I won't progress. Therefore this 'en' really had me stuck. Thanks for your help.